# What is the "routeName" in route() function of Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In [official doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-route):

```
$url = route('routeName');
```

In my daily usage of Laravel, I always write route as:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('main');
});

Route::get('/test', 'TestController@test');
```

There is no name of Route rules...

So what is the "routeName" in route() function of Laravel? Can anyone provide a example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's route name. You can name your routes with [`name()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#named-routes) method or with [`as`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#named-routes) option:

```
Route::get('user/profile', 'UserController@showProfile')->name('profile');

Route::get('user/profile', ['as' => 'profile', 'uses' => 'UserController@showProfile']);
```

You can see a list of route names with `php artisan route:list` command.